# Solving recursive integral equation from Markov transition probability

Tags: markov-process, integral-equations

How do I solve something like:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{-(y - x/2)^2}{2}}f(y)\:\mathrm{d}y$$

for $f(x)$?

Is there also a general formula that this falls under? The closest thing I found was the Fredholm integral equation, but those (I believe) assume that the eigenfunction is linear.

In case it helps, here's my motivation for this problem: I'm trying to find the stationary distribution of a continuous state, discrete time Markov process. I came up with this transition function:

$$P(s_i = x | s_{i-1} = y) = p(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\frac{-(x - y/2)^2}{2}}$$

The idea is that the probability function always brings the mean closer towards $0$ by using a Normal distribution with mean $\mu = y/2$. I then tried to solve the stationary distributions as follows

$$\pi_x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(y, x)\pi_y \:\mathrm{d}y$$

At this point, I'm stuck. (I got the original equation by setting $\pi_x = f(x)$ for clarity.) This might deserve its own questions, but does solving for stationary distributions have its own technique?

Comment: Can you please link (or post if you have to) the original question?  Your notation with the probability transition function seems strange to me.

Comment: I suspect you meant to write that the transition from $y$ to $x$ as  $$p(x, y) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac 12(x - y/2)^2}$$ Maybe just an accidental variable swap?  As you write it, your $p$ has $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x, y) dx = 2$, where as my suggestion has $\dots = 1$.  Also, transitions in your system exponentially approach infinity, so the final state just $\text{dirac}(\infty)$, whereas the suggested change, you approach $0$ with a half life and have a hope of a sensible stationary distribution.

Comment: You're right; I swapped the variables. Thanks for catching that! I came up with this problem, so I don't have a link. I'm wondering if this type of problem falls under some category that could help me get started. (Either solving these types of equations, or solving steady state distributions differently)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm a couple minutes from having an answer for you.

Comment: Awesome! Also, for initial condition, I'm hoping that it won't matter, just as the initial state for (regular) Markov chains doesn't matter when looking at the steady state distribution.

Comment: You are correct that initial distribution doesn't matter.  I was hoping to use it to find a partial answer, but as it turns out, since we can find a complete answer my comment was unnecessary and now is deleted.

Comment: Veech: This may be irrelevant to you but note that the accepted answer (starting at "[A]nsatz") would be considered as non rigorous by most mathematicians. By contrast, @Ilya's answer describes a fully rigorous approach... if only one follows it.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at it again and understood what he was saying. Thanks for the the comment.

Comment: @Did Since my use of the word "ansatz" didn't fool you (I kid), I'm curious what part of my solution you consider non-rigorous?  I thought I pretty well established (without actually writing out the by-the-book induction) that the solution was a normal curve centered at the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, notice that your equation is linear, hence it either has a unique (zero) solution, or infinitely many of them which you can obtain by scaling/taking linear combinations. Of course, in your case you may be only interested in probability distributions, yet the original equation is given in the form $f = Af$ where $A$ is not contractive (and in fact has an eigenvalue of $1$), so I'm not sure there are general methods to solve such problems in Fredholm theory. Unless you know how to incorporate the condition $\int f = 1$ in a smart way.

This issue would be present in all problems where you want to find stationary distribution, so I would suggest look for probabilistic methods rather than methods from analysis. For example, your MC can be represented as
$$
  x_{n+1} = \frac12 x_n + \xi_n
$$ 
where $\xi_n$ are iid standard Gaussian random variables. Now, can you express $x_{n+1}$ through $x_0$ and $\xi_0,\dots,\xi_n$? What is the limit when $n\to\infty$, does the distribution of $x_0$ matter? Another idea is that whenever you have linear Gaussian dynamics, I'd try $f$ being Gaussian with unknown parameters, and check whether you can find values of parameters that solve the problem.

**Updated:** To address your latter point, everything depends on the source of the problem. If your integral equation comes from some probabilistic problem (as in the case of OP) you can do at least two things:

1. Forget the probabilistic underlying and just try to solve the equation using some general methods. I guess as in theory of Fredholm equations you could try out some Laplace/Fourier transform to get a nicer equation and solve it. However, as I said, one of the drawbacks of such approach is that invariant distribution equations always have an infinite number of solutions which makes perfect sense from the probabilistic perspective, but I'm not sure whether general methods of solving integral equations are fine-tuned to such setting.
2. Try to solve it using probabilistic methods: not only it is more "natural" and hence you have intuition of what's going on at each step, also as you could notice such solution can be much faster/simpler (compare with the one outlined in an answer by DanielV).

Note that you can always try to reduce any linear integral equation $f = \int Kf $ to a problem of finding invariant distribution of some Markov Chain, however there is no guarantee such chain will exist: for that $K$ must be a stochastic kernel - for example, in your example of $xy/2$ you'd have to normalize it to integrate to $1$. In your original case everything worked out since the source of the problem was probabilistic. Now, if your question is how to obtain a dynamic representation via iid $\xi$ given a stochastic kernel, yet again although such representation always exists but the proof of this fact is not constructive, so in general you just need to try to find it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into these suggestions. Is there an easy way to tell whether or not equations like these can be solve in closed form? e.g. Does A have to be contractive? Also, it sounds like you're suggesting that probabilistic methods are the way to go regardless. Are there other options? One thing that popped in my head is that if this was a regular finite Markov Chain, we'd just have to solve a finite system of linear equations. Analogously, here we'd be trying to solve an infinite system of nonlinear equations. Does this train of thought lead to something promising?

Comment: Also, how do you know that the $\xi_i$'s are independent? It seems like they're dependent, since $\xi_i$ will determine (in a probability sense) the next state, which will determine $\xi_{i+1}$.

Comment: @Veech first of all, equations are still linear. Regarding the $\xi$, just check straight that my representation exactly gives you correct transition probabilities, so why shall one take them to be dependent.

Comment: How would I solve this problem if instead of having a normal distribution centered around $-y/2$, I had $xy/2$ or something where it isn't possible to convert it easily to something like $x_{n+1} = c*x_n + ...$? Are there probabilistic methods to handle that? Also, if $A$ is contractive, what would the next steps be? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Veech: see the update

Answer (score 2):

We are given a discrete step continuous state transition system from state $y$ to state $x$ as

$$M[y, x] = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac 12(x - y/2)^2}$$

which has the following characteristics

- If you are at $x$, your destination is a normal curve from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ centered at $x/2$ with a variance of $1$

So you can see that in this system, you are statistically going to approach $0$ with some variance.  Define $*$ as
$$(M*N)[y, x] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} M[y, u]\cdot N[u, x] du$$

The steady state transition matrix is given by $M * M * M \dots = M^{\infty}$.

We can tell right away that 
$$\begin{align}
M^2[y, x] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} M[y, u]\cdot M[u, x] du \\
          &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 \left(\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac 12(u - y/2)^2}\right) 
 \left(\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac 12(x - u/2)^2}\right) du \\
          &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{5\pi}} e^{-\frac 1{40}y^2 - \frac 15 xy + \frac 25 x^2}
\end{align}$$

Which is a normal curve peaking at $x = y/4$.  Similarly,

$$M^4[y, x] = \frac 45 \sqrt{\frac{10}{17\pi}}e^{-\frac 1{680}y^2 + \frac 4{85} xy - \frac {32}{85} x^2}$$

which is a normal curve peaking at $x = y/16$.  So each step of the transition does indeed move the distribution closer to a normal curve peaking at $x = 0$.  Define ansatz :

$$M^{\infty}[y, x] = N[y, x] = Re^{-Ax^2}$$

with the constraint that $N$ is stochastic so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} N[y, x] dx = 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sqrt{\pi}R = \sqrt{A}$.  We wish to find:

$$\begin{align}
N &= N*M \\
Re^{-Ax^2} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Re^{-Au^2} \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac 12(x - u/2)^2} du \\
\sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}}e^{-Ax^2} &= \sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}} \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-Au^2} \cdot e^{-\frac 12(x - u/2)^2} du \\
\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-Ax^2} &= \sqrt{\frac{8\pi}{8A + 1}} e^{-4Ax^2/(8A + 1)} \\
A &= \frac 38
\end{align}$$

So your final steady state is going to be

$$M^\infty[y, x] = \sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}e^{-\frac 38 x^2}$$

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you!

Comment: I asked the other person who answered these questions: to find the steady state distribution for a continuous state, discrete time MC, are there other approaches? One thing that popped in my head is that if this was a regular finite Markov Chain, we'd just have to solve a finite system of linear equations. Analogously, here we'd be trying to solve an infinite system of nonlinear equations. Does this train of thought lead to something promising? This this approach in mind, does this mean $M^\infty$ is the eigenvector of $N$? How do we generally find these eigenvectors?

Comment: The main difference of thinking of continuous state transition systems analogously to finite state one is that the finite state ones are easily computable.  However, in this case, we got lucky that an easy closed form integral existed, but to find a general computable expression is a pipe dream.  As far as eignvector goes, that depends on how you define it.  Certainly $M*M^\infty = 1 \cdot M^\infty$, so in that respect it is an "eigenvector" (more of an eigen...distribution?).  There are also possibly an uncountably infinite number of "eigenvalues", to extend the analogy.

Comment: While I was looking up similar problems, I came across Brownian motion (for this type of MC/general distribution problem) and Fredholm theory (for this type of integral equation). Do you know if there are other topics that I could look into that may be closer to what I'm looking for?

Comment: I've asked that myself.  It certainly seems unpopular to approach this kind of problem from this point of view.  You can try "Spectral Theory", and to a lesser degree, and "Banach Spaces" "Hilbert Spaces", but I think it is most common to discuss these problems in the context of markov chains.  It's just too many people writing about these things that aren't actually interested in solving problems, it creates a great deal of worthless crap to wade through.